# gwt and google maps v3 api which library

Tags: google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I'm building an app in gwt and I want to use google maps api V3 but I already searched and tried some libraries and can't find out which one is better. My app will have some complex use off google maps like polylines, routes etc..

Now I have 3 options:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/detail?name=gwt-maps-3.8.0-pre1.zip
but that one is deprecated.

this one:
https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api

and finally I can use JSNI but I think it's not the right choice.

So I need help to choose one above or other library that I didn't mention.
Thanks.

Comment: Where do you see that `gwt-maps-3.8.0` is deprecated?

Comment: Sorry my mistake it's not deprecated but in the wiki says: "Status: This library is currently alpha. Don't use it in critical applications just yet!"

Comment: OK. Still GMail was in beta for a looong time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as first library is in early development stage, i suggest you to use second one, to be honest it is quite nice, i was using it before i moved to openlayers.

any way seems like both of them are just wrapper around original google map library, so i don't think moving from one to another in future will be difficult.